# Is `transform-origin` only applicable to `rotate` in terms of 2D transforms?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I’m a bit confused on the idea of the `transform-origin` property, mainly its uses. Does `transform-origin` only apply to `rotate` in terms of 2D transforms?

Comment: Are you looking for this? `transform-origin` works with 2D and 3D
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

Comment: It’s also applicable to `skew` and `scale`. See the [examples in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin#Examples).

Comment: @MHHabib _“in terms of 2D transforms”_ implies that the OP is only asking about 2D transforms.

Answer (score 5):

`transform-origin` apply to linear transformation. To make it easy, `transform-origin` apply to all the transformation and the only exception is translation which is an affine transformation.

Any kind of transfomation can be written using a matrix like below:

```
matrix(a, b, c, d, tx, ty)
```

where

> a b c d
>
> Are `<number>`s describing the linear transformation.
>
> tx ty
>
> Are `<number>`s describing the translation to apply. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix())</sup>

If b,c are different from 0 or a,d different from 1 then `transform-origin` will have an effect on your transformation. If b,c are equal to 0 and a,d equal to 1 then `transform-origin` will have no effect.

Only `translate()` or an identity transformation (skew(0), scale(1), rotate(0), etc) will give you 0 in c,b and 1 in a,d

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#MatrixDefined):

> [image]

If we have the identity in the red part then it's most likely a translation or nothing (if `e` and `f` are 0).

Example to illustrate the case of using a translation:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  background:red;
  transform:translate(10px,50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="transform-origin:0 0"></div>
<div class="box" style="transform-origin:100% 0"></div>
<div class="box" style="transform-origin:50px 10px"></div>
<div class="box" style="transform-origin:9999px -9999px"></div>
```

For more details you can follow this link: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-rendering where you will find the full explanation about how transformation is done and how `transform-origin` is applied

> The transformation matrix is computed from the transform and transform-origin properties as follows:
>
> 1. Start with the identity matrix.
> 2. Translate by the computed X and Y of transform-origin
> 3. Multiply by each of the transform functions in transform property from left to right
> 4. Translate by the negated computed X and Y values of transform-origin

It's clear that the (2) and (4) are opposite actions and in order to disable each other we need to either have no transformation in (3) or a simple translation.