Can someone explain how the css matrix transform works mathematically?
From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix
writing the css property
transform: matrix(a, b, c, d, tx, ty)

is equivalent to matrix(scaleX(), skewY(), skewX(), scaleY(), translateX(), translateY()).
It is also equivalent to the following matrix for homogenous coordinates on RP^2 or Cartesian coordinates on R^3
a   c   tx
b   d   ty
0   0   1

Here's what doesn't make sense to me: it's possible to apply this matrix transform on a 2D vector, e.g. (x,y), (width,height), an html element with a 2D position.
This shouldn't be possible because the columns of the matrix must match the number of rows in the vector.
So how is this being calculated? There is also a definition for cartesian coordinates on R^2 but it discards tx and ty which are definitely being calculated in the examples on a 2D element.
I have one specific question:
What mathematical operation is being used here? It cannot be basic matrix multiplication because the matrix columns do not not match the vector dimensions. Yet they represent this as a transformation matrix. So it is using some kind of linear algebra I do not know most likely. What is the math?

I'm not sure exactly what your problem is, but note that in the reference you give this is stated: "However, one major transformation is not linear, and therefore must be special-cased when using this notation: translation. The translation vector (tx, ty) must be expressed separately, as two additional parameters." - that is I think that they are using a notation, but it's not applied exactly as you would in a mathematical sense, the translations are a special case and treated separately.

read the Spec for more accurate detail: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#mathematical-description

The issue is that the number of rows in the matrix don't match the number of columns in the vector to be equal (assuming DOM elements are 2D). Looking at the spec. linked by @TemaniAfif I see it defines a 4x4 matrix which again is the wrong shape. As for a non-linear transformation or special-cased transf., brought up by A Haworth I wonder why are they representing it as a 3x3 matrix? I actually don't see the quote you copied in the reference. I have a basic understanding of linear algebra, but not advanced. Trying to walk through the math and any clarification helps

Update: I think the answer lies in the fact it is using a homogenous coordinate system, not a cartesian coordinate system. So these 2D positions on the DOM (x,y) are actually 3D (x,y,1). When I saw the coordinates were homogenous in RP^2, I thought that implied it was 2 dimensional. I also see in the docs a reference to cartesian coordinates with the same matrix definition. This brought me to this video which I found helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-xwmTODTUI

Here are a few of my answers where I am doing some matrix calculation, it may help you better understand: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672795/8620333 (2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/64962024/8620333 (3) https://stackoverflow.com/a/65161832/8620333

"I actually don't see the quote you copied in the reference." Apologies, the quote I gave is from a link referenced by your link. It is where they are describing :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function and I found this a bit easier to grasp as it spells things out for 2D etc.

Answering my own question as I have discovered more thanks to other comments and also time.
This is because it is representing in a homogeneous coordinate system.
Problem: a translation is not a linear transformation because it changes the origin. In a linear system, T(0,0) == (0,0) but a translation makes it so T(0,0) != (0,0)
Solution 1: using a cartesian coordinate system, perform 2D matrix multiplication, and then add the translation:
M*p+tr

# where
M = a 2x2 marix
p = a 2D point (x,y)
tr = a translation (tx, ty)

Solution 2: Another solution is to use a homogenous coordinate system which will move the problem up one dimension
M*p

M = a 3x3 matrix
p = a 3D vector that represents a 2D point (x,y,1)

The resulting matrix multiplication will perform a linear transformation of p by shearing in the 3rd dimension.
This can be generalized to 3D graphics as well, and is why in 3D graphics programming you will often see Vector4s.
YouTube videos for more information:
Why use 4x4 matrices for 3D graphics? A good place to start https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Do_vEjd6gF0
Quick understanding of homogeneous coordinates https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-xwmTODTUI
